# Jquery: using hover to change css attributes

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make a button for my website, which has a changing color hover effect. It can simply be done in css in this way:

```
.button{
    color: green;
}

.button:hover {
    background : green;
    color: black;
}
```

However, I wanted to give this a nice transition using JQuery (since I'm trying to learn it). Here's one of the codes I've tried so far:

```
$(function() {
    $('.button').on('mouseover', function() {
        $(this).css({
            "background" : "green", 
            "color" : "black",
        })
    })
})
```

I've tried it in so many other ways, like using the "hover" function instead of "on(mouseover)", using the addClass method, and so on. But in all of those, nothing happens when I hover the mouse on the button. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: add `})` at the end of your script, then try again.

Comment: Check your console for errors it's probably because you didn't close the function, check Sphinx's comment.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It was a problem in the actual question text (I fixed it), but in my JS file everything is closed right. I get no errors in the console, but my code just doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have nice transitions in css! A simple implementation with `transition` is below. More complicated effects can be achieved using `@keyframes`

```css
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    background-color: #0f82e0;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #27b258;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">I&#39;m a button!</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip! But how can I do it in Jquery?

Comment: @LucasBernardi You've actually stumbled across one of the more annoying parts of `.animate()` which is that it doesn't nativley support colour transitions. You'd need the help of a plugin like jQuery UI (https://jqueryui.com/animate/) to accomplish that. The alternative is you use `.addClass` and `.removeClass` (or `.toggleClass`) and continue using a CSS transition, just controlled through the addition and removal of a second class name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) to smooth out the effect. There are jQuery libraries to handle this, but CSS is the better way. You'll need to [check for feature support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) and use [jQuery transitions](https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) only for browsers that need it.

EDIT: @Lucas Bernardi since you insist on doing this with jQuery instead of native CSS methods, [you can use `.animate()`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) with the [jQuery.Color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color). But for browsers that support it, you are better off with CSS transitions.

From the `.animate()` documentation:

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color plugin is used).

Example usage from the jQuery.Color documentation:

```
jQuery("#go").click(function () {
  jQuery("#block").animate({
    backgroundColor: "#abcdef"
  }, 1500);
});
jQuery("#sat").click(function () {
  jQuery("#block").animate({
    backgroundColor: jQuery.Color({
      saturation: 0
    })
  }, 1500);
});
```